# Web api Owin Authentication retrieve user information from key

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

Hi all first of all i have a little knowledge about asp.net identity and Owin authentication , Please pardon me if my question is incorrect .

I have a web-api project which is authenticating Using Active directory, and the client which consumes the  api is iphone app. i have to use Owin Authentication in-order to secure the username and password . Also i am integrating Microsoft dynamic CRM  with the web-api. In-order to authorize the CRM,  we need the username and password which is encrypted in Owin `KEY`

But i dont know how to decrypt the user information from the owin key can anyone please help My code for Owin authentication is as given below

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Signin
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="user"></param>
        /// <param name="options"></param>
        /// <param name="authManager"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string SignIn(User user, OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options, IAuthenticationManager authManager)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity identity = SetClaims(user, options);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());

            var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
            ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
           // ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(user.AuthenticationExpiry));
            ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(180));
            authManager.SignIn(identity);

            return options.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
        }

        private ClaimsIdentity SetClaims(User user, OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(options.AuthenticationType);

            string userdata = user.UserName +"~"+ user.Password;

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, userdata.ToString()));
            return identity;
        }
```

How to authorize each request using the KEY. because the iphone app only provide the Key which I had given on user login . Can anyone please help

Comment: You mean you want the username/password that the client used to `POST` to the `/token` endpoint ?

Comment: yes i got the solution the problem was i forgot add 'bearer' word prefix on header